# How to apply the minDF feature extractor CountVectorizer parameter to each label separately, and not to the entire dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, feature-extraction, countvectorizer

I am new to Apache Spark and faced the following problem:
there is a dataset:

```
| label    | words               |
| -------- | ------------------- |
| 0        | word1 word2 word3   |
| 0        | word4 word1 word5   |
| 0        | word6 word7 word8   |
| 1        | word9 word10        |
| 1        | word9 word11        |
```

If you use **CountVectorizer** with **setMinDF (0.5)** with this dataset, then words **word1** and **word9** will not get into the dictionary, since each of them occurs in less than 50% of documents in the dataset.
How can you apply **minDF** to each label separately to get **word1** and **word9** into the dictionary?

My current code:

```
Dataset<Row> wordsData = <my dataset>;

CountVectorizer cv = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features");
cv.setMinDF(0.5);

cvModel = cv.fit(wordsData);        
cvModel.save(extractorModelFile);   // SAVE MODEL

Dataset<Row> rescaledData = cvModel.transform(wordsData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `minDF` to `1.0` (its default value), all the words will be in the vocabulary.

```scala
val df = Seq(0 -> "word1 word2 word3",
             0 -> "word1 word2 word3",
             0 -> "word6 word7 word8",
             1 -> "word9 word10",
             1 -> "word9 word11")
    .toDF("label", "words").withColumn("words", split('words, " "))

val cv = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").setMinDF(1d)

val model = cv.fit(df).transform(df)
model.vocabulary
```

```
res: Array[String] = Array(word9, word3, word2, word1, word11, word8, word7, word6, word10)
```